# Chrome error: Uncaught SyntaxError: <unknown message reserved_word>

Tags: javascript

Okay heres my problem:

Im trying to extend the dom but for one of my prototype functions, it throws an error.
The error is for the function hasClass. I used the reserved word Element earlier in that script so i dont understand why he is throwing the error only there?

```
Element.prototype.hasClass = function (class) {
    return this.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+class+'(\\s|$)'));
}

Element.prototype.addClass = function (class) {
    this.className = this.className + " " + class;
}

Element.prototype.removeClass = function (class) {
    if (this.hasClass(class)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+class+'(\\s|$)');
        this.className = this.className.replace(reg,' ');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class` is a reserved word. Try renaming it.

Here's a whole list of reserved words in JavaScript:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: Wow didnt knew class is a reserved word :O

Thanks worked like a charm after renaming :)

Answer (score 1):

`class` is a reserved word. You can't use it. Try to rename it