# Why is my Cordova Android app throwing a "reserved word" error when defining an object using a class declaration?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, reserved-words

My JavaScript app works well in a web browser, but displays an error when running the app on Android using Cordova: 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: <unknown message reserved_word>`

This error is tied to the first line of my class declaration in Javascript, as follows:

```
class ABC {
    constructor() {
        ...
    }
    ...
    someMethod() {
    }
}
```

Could anyone please offer any suggestions about what might be causing this error?

It looks like I am using the word "Class" the way it is intended to be used in JavaScript, per the following reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome error: Uncaught SyntaxError: <unknown message reserved\_word>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036427/chrome-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unknown-message-reserved-word)

Comment: This does not look like a duplicate to me, since I am using "class" according to the reference link provided which states that JavaScript classes were introduced in ECMAScript 2015.  The other posting is not using "class" in this way.

Comment: Yes but what the version of your WebView in the mobile? it could be that its not upto date

Comment: From DevTools in Chrome, I see WebView v33.0.0.0

Comment: Ok, got it!  You are correct, Lasitha.  I was able to verify this was the root cause of the error, so now looking into other options such as using JS without "class" in order to continue supporting this version of Kitkat / WebView v33.  Thank you!

Comment: Awesome, I have updated an answer so that it would help others who might read this in future, use a transpiler like Babel don't change your code. Transpile it support older browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue had occurred due to the WebView of the browser been v33.0.0.0 in Kitkat which doesn't support the class keyword natively. You can use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to make your code compatible with older browsers.